# Handle states in character in functional programming way

Tags: design-patterns

How to handle any change of state of a character with functional programming?

If I'm using functional programming the character should be stateless, in my understanding. With that said, I should instantiate a new character every time a position, for example, is changed. Is this correct? This doesn't sound very efficient, but I might be wrong. I'm tinkering before start implementing and wanted to be sure this is the right way.

Thanks.

Comment: Game development rarely uses purely functional styles. About the closest we get is highly data-oriented design, like ECS systems operating on buffers of data like a giant map call. May I ask why you're looking at functional style as a key goal for your character update logic?

Comment: I've used ECS and I loved it. I'm looking at functional style, because I've used in other projects and I liked it a lot.

Comment: Here’s a link to a series of short articles about implementing pac-man in a purely functional way: https://prog21.dadgum.com/23.html It doesn’t come down one way or the other on whether this is a good idea or not.

Answer (score 1):

What your looking for is FRP game development.

**Some Video Introductions:**

- ["Controlling Time and Space: understanding the many formulations of FRP" by Evan Czaplicki](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Agu6jipKfYw)
- [Bodil Stokke: Reactive Game Development For The Discerning Hipster [JSConf2014]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8mmAu7ZR9Y)
- Love this talk with Carmack, describes his experiences with purely functional programming in game development [John Carmack's keynote at Quakecon 2013 part 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PhArSujR_A)

It is 100% possible and preferable to make the core game logic in a purely functional way, the industry as a whole is simply behind, stuck in one paradigm of thinking.

Its possible to do it in Unity as well.

- [Unity Redux Library](https://github.com/mattak/Unidux)

To answer the question a new game state will be updated/created every time something moves, as carmack says in his talk, it's not a problem. The drastic reduction in cognitive overhead that comes from a purely functional, highly maintainable, flexible architecture far out ways the performance hit, if it exists at all.